# Is there a way to easily track multiple OSGi services?

Tags: osgi

I am looking for way to track multiple OSGI services without the hassle of creating many ServiceTrackers.

Something like that:

```
library.track(Service1.class, Service2.class, Service3.class, new Tracker(){
    void servicesAdded(Service1 s1, Service2 s2, Service3 s3){
        //do something with all 3 services
    }
    void servicesRemoved(){
        //one of the services is not available, no operation possible
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not track more than one service using just basic OSGi APIs. The easiest way to achieve this is to create a declarative services component with some mandatory service references and immediate=true. The @Activate method of this service will be called when all mandatory references are present.

```
@Component(immediate=true)
public class MyComponent {
    @Reference
    ServiceA sa;

    @Reference
    ServiceB sb;

    @Reference
    ServiceC sc;

    @Activate
    public void activate() {

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks very good. Do I get this right that method annotated with @Deactivate will be called if one of the dependencies is no longer available?

Comment: Yes. When one of the services is not available anymore the @Deactivate method is called and the instance of the component is destroyed.